# Limit paths in Kestrel to specific port (port filtering) in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-2.2

In a .NET Core web project (API, .NET Core 2.2, Kestrel) I implemented the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.

The health checks support the options to be reachable over a definable port.

From that on for the new features I get the requirment to limit the calls to the "management port" (the same one that the health checks use).

**So my question is how to implement a port filter allowing calls to specific paths only when they come over a defined port? (like health checks do).**

Scenario:
App is running on standard port 5000.

Kestrel has defined to listen to two ports

```
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

  // ...

  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
    {
      int regularPort = 5000;
      int managementPort = 5001;

      options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, regularPort);
      options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, managementPort);
    }
  )
  ;
```

Now in the startup configure method I use

```
 app.UseHealthChecks("/health/ready", managementPort, ...
```

which allows me to access the /health/ready only over 5001.

But over 5001 everything else is reachable too. Anyway to disable that?

Now the other features (metrics) etc should also be reachable over 5001 but not over 5000.